# How do I randomly set an integer to a class name based on array length?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to randomly set some css rules to different section tags, but I don't know how many section tags I will end up with. If there are 10 section tags, each section should have a random class name between `section0` to `section9`. It needs to be randomized and not in order.

I read about `document.getElementByTagName` and I'm able to assign class names with an integer by using a for loop, but I'm not sure where and how to implement `Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)` and return it correctly.

```
   function myFunction(){
    var randomize = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
    for (i = 0; i <= randomize.length; i++) {
        randomize[i].className = "section" + i;
        }
    }
```

I've tried `i = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomize.length);`

and return `randomize[i].className = "section" + i;`

but that does not seem to work. I'm trying to incorporate two things I've been reading about but I'm not sure how to correctly do so.

Comment: Should the randomization not be repetative?

Comment: Just replace min and max with 0 and 9. Try something like this: Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

Comment: Correct, the randomization should not be repetitive.

Comment: What you really want to do is shuffle your array of sections

Comment: What you want is to construct an array with the numbers of 0 - randomize.length, and then shuffle the array, and then as you're iterating over randomize, use that shuffled array to choose the class names

Comment: Show your non-working prototype in a CodePen and I'm sure someone will be able to show you what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of a solution randomly generates a number dependent upon how many sections there are.  It keeps track of the numbers already used in an array.  So long as a number is already used, it will keep trying.

```js
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
var usedValues = [];

[...sections].forEach(function(section){
  var classAssigned = false;
  
  while (!classAssigned) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 * sections.length) % sections.length;
    
    if (classAssigned = !usedValues.includes(randomNumber)) {
      section.classList.add('section'+ randomNumber);
      usedValues.push(randomNumber);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<section>A</section>
<section>B</section>
<section>C</section>
<section>D</section>
<section>E</section>
<section>F</section>
<section>G</section>
<section>H</section>
<section>I</section>
<section>J</section>
<section>K</section>
<section>L</section>
<section>M</section>
<section>N</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You not only showed me a better way to look at this problem, but taught me some shorthand that will go a long way.

Comment: Awesome, :).  What shorthand did you take away?  Out of curiosity. @kingsman